# How To Have Multiple href Class Selectors Under One Id in CSS?

Tags: css

Absolutely simple, yes?

No, not really: the following (as I understand it) should work to give me multiple href class selectors under one id in CSS but does not work (the first code block is the default, followed by the code block for, in this case, one other class):

```
#layoutA a:link {
    color: red; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA a:visited {
    color: red; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA a:hover {
    color: red; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA a:active {
    color: hotpink; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA a:focus {
    color: hotpink; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}



#layoutA .class1 a:link {
    color: red; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA .class1 a:visited {
    color: red; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA .class1 a:hover {
    color: red; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA .class1 a:active {
    color: hotpink; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA .class1 a:focus {
    color: hotpink; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}
```

...so I need to know if this is actually possible in CSS (and, if so, how?), or whether I should just continue using different ids for every href link that needs styling with a different colour scheme?

Comment: What seems to go wrong? It might help to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: From your description I cannot visualize the structure of the HTML, it may be easier to post it rather than describe it.

Comment: On a side not, your CSS seems to suggest you have 2 html elements using the same ID. The same ID can't be used twice per page. In regards to your question, if you provide some example HTML to show the problem you are having, we will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your structure your code works.

According to your CSS, any links that you want styled by `class1` has to be wrapped in a wrapper with that class.

However, if you are giving the link itself the class, I have included a set of styles as class2 to give an example on how to do that properly.

```css
#layoutA a:link {
    color: red; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA a:visited {
    color: red; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA a:hover {
    color: green; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA a:active {
    color: hotpink; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA a:focus {
    color: hotpink; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}



#layoutA .class1 a:link {
    color: red; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA .class1 a:visited {
    color: red; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA .class1 a:hover {
    color: black; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA .class1 a:active {
    color: hotpink; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA .class1 a:focus {
    color: hotpink; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA a.class2:link {
    color: black; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA a.class2:visited {
    color: red; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA a.class2:hover {
    color: green; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA a.class2 a:active {
    color: hotpink; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

#layoutA a.class2:focus {
    color: hotpink; font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="layoutA">
    <a href="#">This is styled by the first set</a>
    <div class="class1"><a href="#">This is styled by class1</a></div>
    <a class="class2" href="#">This is styled by Class2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, - that is very helpful and does work. It also helps if I remember to change the colour scheme colours in the class1, class2, etc. selectors, plus I was having problems with Firefox's delightful habit of failing, or refusing, to clear the cache fully.